# No information available for Provided link in Twitter Status update API

Tags: android, twitter, status, tweets

I am working in an application which requires to send tweets on Twitter Account. I am successfully able to login and fetching details of user. But however when i try to update status Code of Twitter. It's throwing a runtime exception as per below:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.
```

Even url is not available which is being shown in Exception. This is truly confusing.
i am using following code. Please help.

```
 AccessToken accessToken = getAccessToken();
         ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
         cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
           .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
           .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
           .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken.getToken())
           .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessToken.getTokenSecret());
         TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
         Twitter twitter = tf.getSingleton();
        // twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        String latestStatus = "Hello Dude";
        try {

            twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(latestStatus);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Successfully tweet==="+status.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception in Ststus update in android=="+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using same library for sending tweet on Twitter. You might have code wrong to work it proper.

Please refer this for sending tweet:
[Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)

Also check my code below to understand more on how to handle twitter error response also.

Code:

```
private final TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String value) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("Posting from Twitter application...");
            //status.media(new File(sPhotoPATH));
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //getFriendListForApp();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to connect Twitter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //getFriendListForApp();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(String value) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to connect Twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
};
```

and another is:

```
public void updateStatus(final StatusUpdate status) throws Exception {
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Posting...");
    mProgressDlg.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
                i = 0;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Not Posted: In Catch");

                message = e.getErrorMessage();
                System.out.println("MESSAGE:::: "+message);
                //asdasd
                //Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //e.getMessage();
                i= 1;
            }

            mPostHandler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt from this.

Enjoy Coding... :)